# How to determine compiler name or vendor in Autoconf?

Tags: c++, autoconf, compiler-flags

I'm working on Solaris with SunCC. Autoconf's `AC_COMPILE_IFELSE` and `AC_LINK_IFELSE` are misdetecting compiler features. Autoconf is reporting features are available even though the compiler rejects them with messages such as *`illegal option`*.

```
$ echo 'int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {}' > test.C
$ /opt/solarisstudio12.4/bin/CC test.C
$ /opt/solarisstudio12.4/bin/CC -msse4.2 -msha test.C
CC: Warning: Option -msse4.2 passed to ld, if ld is invoked, ignored otherwise
CC: Warning: Option -msha passed to ld, if ld is invoked, ignored otherwise
ld: fatal: option '-h a' is incompatible with building a dynamic executable
$ /opt/solarisstudio12.4/bin/CC -xarch=sha test.C
CC: Warning: illegal use of -xarch option, illegal value ignored: sha
```

I'd like to try to workaround the misdetections, but I need to know the compiler to do it. Autoconf has some macros that provide [canonicalized names for CPU, Vendor and OS](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.62/html_node/Canonicalizing.html), but they do not appear to include the compiler or its vendor.

How do we detect or determine compiler name or vendor in Autoconf?

---

Adding the following is not really helpful since it does not identify the compiler.

```
AC_MSG_NOTICE(["Build: $build"])
AC_MSG_NOTICE(["Compiler: $compiler"])
```

Then:

```
CXX=/opt/solarisstudio12.4/bin/CC ./configure
...

configure: "Build: i386-pc-solaris2.11"
configure: "Compiler: /opt/solarisstudio12.4/bin/CC"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a standard way to do this.

We manually check for the existence of compiler macros according to [predef.sourceforge.net](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Compilers/) and perhaps more sources like `cc --version`, the cc's command name, the operating system name, ...).

I.e. you compile a program, and check for defines.
If it doesn't exist / the programm #errors out -> not SunCC.

It looks messy, but here is an example straight from the [Score-P](http://score-p.org) source (vendor/common/build-config/m4/ax_compiler_vendor.m4). Maybe you can take some inspiration from it:

```
AC_DEFUN([AX_COMPILER_VENDOR],
[AC_CACHE_CHECK([for _AC_LANG compiler vendor], ax_cv_[]_AC_LANG_ABBREV[]_compiler_vendor,
  dnl Please add if possible support to ax_compiler_version.m4
  [# note: don't check for gcc first since some other compilers define __GNUC__
  vendors="intel:     __ICC,__ECC,__INTEL_COMPILER
           ibm:       __xlc__,__xlC__,__IBMC__,__IBMCPP__
           pathscale: __PATHCC__,__PATHSCALE__
           clang:     __clang__
           cray:      _CRAYC
           fujitsu:   __FUJITSU
           gnu:       __GNUC__
           sun:       __SUNPRO_C,__SUNPRO_CC
           hp:        __HP_cc,__HP_aCC
           dec:       __DECC,__DECCXX,__DECC_VER,__DECCXX_VER
           borland:   __BORLANDC__,__CODEGEARC__,__TURBOC__
           comeau:    __COMO__
           kai:       __KCC
           lcc:       __LCC__
           sgi:       __sgi,sgi
           microsoft: _MSC_VER
           metrowerks: __MWERKS__
           watcom:    __WATCOMC__
           portland:  __PGI
           tcc:       __TINYC__
           unknown:   UNKNOWN"
  for ventest in $vendors; do
    case $ventest in
      *:) vendor=$ventest; continue ;;
      *)  vencpp="defined("`echo $ventest | sed 's/,/) || defined(/g'`")" ;;
    esac
    AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM(,[
      #if !($vencpp)
        thisisanerror;
      #endif
    ])], [break])
  done
  ax_cv_[]_AC_LANG_ABBREV[]_compiler_vendor=`echo $vendor | cut -d: -f1`
 ])
])
```

Comment: Thanks Ronny. It is interesting Score-P decided to use preprocessor macros rather than the string from `$compiler --version`,  `$compiler --qversion` or `$compiler -V`. It seems like there's equal amount of work to dump the version string versus the macros (many compilers are different). I'll have to think about that. Would you happen to know why preprocessor macros were used?

Comment: I think parsing --version is more messy, and the strings / keywords can change between versions. I wasn't involved in that decision. But I think it makes sense for the compiler. It's a reliable source. See predef.sourceforge.net -> compilers. For platforms/libraries/other things we do use other sources. E.g. how to find out whether it's a Cray system, or linux cluster etc.

Comment: Thanks Ronny. I'm going with a compiler string rather than preprocessor macros. Our [`GNUmakefile`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/GNUmakefile) uses both techniques, but it has traditionally used `--version` and friends for compiler version strings.

Comment: I know this is old, but it's worth noting that this is available from the Autoconf archive: https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_compiler_vendor.html

Answer (score 1):

As @Ronny stated, there does not appear to be a standard way to determine the compiler vendor. Detecting a vendor is important during configure for tasks like working around Autoconf bugs during misdetection: `CC: Warning: illegal use of -xarch option, illegal value ignored: sha`.

@Ronny showed how to do it with preprocessor macros. We avoided that because of the way compilers pretend to be GCC. Both Clang and Intel's compiler defines `__GNUC__`, and probably others do it, too.

Here's how to do it with version strings in `configure.ac`:

```
## Determine the compiler's vendor.

COMPILER_VERSION=`"$CXX" --version 2>/dev/null`

## IBM xlC test if COMPILER_VERSION is empty
if test x"$COMPILER_VERSION" = "x"; then
   COMPILER_VERSION=`"$CXX" -qversion 2>/dev/null`
fi

## SunCC test if COMPILER_VERSION is empty
if test x"$COMPILER_VERSION" = "x"; then
   COMPILER_VERSION=`"$CXX" -V 2>&1`
fi
```

Then, the vendor can be used like:

```
IS_SUN_COMPILER=`echo $COMPILER_VERSION | $EGREP -i -c -E 'Sun C\+\+'`
echo "IS_SUN_COMPILER: $IS_SUN_COMPILER"
...

## This block handles SunCC.
if test "$IS_SUN_COMPILER" -ne "0"; then    
    ...    
fi
```

Comment: Yeah, you are right about defining multiple macros. Checking multiple sources is probably a good way. I am not particularly fond of --version, because they it likes to change. If you want to extract e.g. the version number of the compiler it gets even messier.